# Flask Socketio server in Docker container - Why random numbers output?

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

I have a Flask server running in a Docker container, launched using Docker compose...
A few times per minute random numbers are printed to the console. I have no idea of the source of these random numbers, nowhere in my code is it printing these numbers. It makes it extremely difficult to debug due to these numbers filling up the entire console output.

Does anyone have any idea where these could be coming from? They are not actually logged to the log file, only the console std out. My guess is that it is something in Flask causing this. It seems to happen whenever a request is made.

Below is an example of what it looks like, ("test-api" is the name of the container), this is not even 1/10 of the actual output from when it occurs...

```
test-api                      | 1656972089
test-api                      | 1656971667
test-api                      | 1656965175
test-api                      | 1656971092
test-api                      | 1656972604
test-api                      | 1656970514
test-api                      | 1656968882
test-api                      | 1656966738
test-api                      | 1656971630
test-api                      | 1656967044
test-api                      | 1656971332
test-api                      | 1656967450
test-api                      | 1656972733
test-api                      | 1656966283
test-api                      | 1656963589
test-api                      | 1656973134
test-api                      | 1656966283
test-api                      | 1656968760
test-api                      | 1656966845
test-api                      | 1656968085
test-api                      | 1656967409
test-api                      | 1656967373
test-api                      | 1656971903
test-api                      | 1656968672
test-api                      | 1656965481
test-api                      | 1656966436
test-api                      | 1656969209
test-api                      | 1656969811
test-api                      | 1656963218
test-api                      | 1656969154172.19.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2022 13:33:23] "GET /test-logged-in HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I am using these versions:

```
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Session==0.3.2
Flask-SocketIO==4.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
...
```

Comment: This isn't enough information. The numbers do not appear to be completely random, they look like Unix timestamps for dates around July 4th 2022 (a month from the date you posted your question). Any significance to dates a month in the future?

Comment: Thanks @MiguelGrinberg your hint lead me in the right direction. Apparently the source of these 'random numbers' is from my log formatter: `file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(         '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '         '[in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))` I removed the `%(asctime)s` while I am debugging to avoid the undesired output. I cannot permanently remove because I will lose timestamps in the log files but good enough for now to avoid these numbers that only appear in the console not the log files! Now they appear much less often if at all sometimes. Thank you sir!

Comment: Actually @MiguelGrinberg the Unix timestamps came back, I now believe it is due to a ton of these print statements I have throughout the code with the argument `"flush=True" ` ex: `print('TEST", flush=True)` I think the 'flush' is causing this.

Comment: I am convinced this is a Flask issue not in my code nor anything to do with Docker. I thoroughly inspected my code and there is absolutely no way this is caused by my code. These random Unix timestamps are printed whenever the route returns an HTTP code. For instance, `@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return {}, 200`